# Can striplines be added to a legend?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When adding stiplines to an SSRS chart, they do not appear as part of the legend.  Is it possible to add definitions to the legend for the stiplines?

Comment: Generally, the striplines should correlate with one of your axes and be defined by the axis label.  What do you envision the definition in the legend to be?

Comment: I have a couple of striplines indicating maximum capability and minimum capability.  I'd for the their definition to be included in the legend.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding an image for a legend.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach.
If strip line is not too complicated and could be described in dataset as series, then move it there and get your legend. Target lines limits, thresholds - all could present in chart as series, just put constant values in corresponding fields.